# Pandas: Remove rows from the dataframe that begin with a letter and save CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here is a sample CSV I'm working with
[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def deleteSearchTerm(inputFile):
#(1) Open the file
    df = pd.read_csv(inputFile)

#(2) Filter every row where the first letter is 's' from search term
    df = df[df['productOMS'].str.contains('^[a-z]+')]
        #REGEX to filter anything that would ^ (start with) a letter

inputFile = inputFile
deleteSearchTerm(inputFile)
```

---

What I want to do:

Anything in the column ProductOMS that begins with a letter would be a row that I don't want. So I'm trying to delete them based on a condition and I was also trying would regular expressions just so I'd get a little bit more comfortable with them.

I tried to do that with:

```
df = df[df['productOMS'].str.contains('^[a-z]+')]
```

where if any of the rows starts with any lower case letter I would drop it (I think)

Please let me know if I need to add anything to my post!

Edit:

Here is a link to a copy of the file I'm working with.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dsw2Ana3WVIheNT43Ad4Dv6C8AIbvAlJ/view?usp=sharing

Another Edit: Here is the dataframe I'm working with

```
productNum,ProductOMS,productPrice
2463448,1002623072,419.95,
2463413,1002622872,289.95,
2463430,1002622974,309.95,
2463419,1002622908,329.95,
2463434,search?searchTerm=2463434,,
2463423,1002622932,469.95,
```

New Edit:
Here's some updated code using an answer

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def deleteSearchTerm(inputFile):
#(1) Open the file

    df = pd.read_csv(inputFile)
    print(df)

#(2) Filter every row where the first letter is 's' from search term
    df = df[~pd.to_numeric(df['ProductOMS'],errors='coerce').isnull()]

    print(df)


inputFile = inputFile
deleteSearchTerm(inputFile)
```

When I run this code and print out the dataframes this gets rid of the rows that start with 'search'. However my CSV file is not updating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you're most likely dealing with mixed data types.

if you just want numeric values you can use `pd.to_numeric`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3,'a12351','123a6']})

df[~pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce').isnull()]

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

but if you only want to test the first letter then :

```
df[~df['A'].astype(str).str.contains('^[a-z]')==True]

       A
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
5  123a6
```

Edit, it seems the first solution works, but you need to write this back to your csv?

you need to use the `to_csv` method, i'd recommend you read 10 minutes to pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

As for your function, lets edit it a little to take a source csv file and throw out an edited version, it will save the file to the same location with `_edited` added on. feel free to edit/change.

```
from pathlib import Path

def delete_search_term(input_file, column):
    """
    Takes in a file and removes any strings from a given column
    input_file : path to your file.
    column : column with strings that you want to remove.

    """
    file_path = Path(input_file)

    if not file_path.is_file():
        raise Exception('This file path is not valid')

    df = pd.read_csv(input_file)

    #(2) Filter every row where the first letter is 's' from search term
    df = df[~pd.to_numeric(df[column],errors='coerce').isnull()]
    print(f"Creating file as:\n{file_path.parent.joinpath(f'{file_path.stem}_edited.csv')}")
    return df.to_csv(file_path.parent.joinpath(f"{file_path.stem}_edited.csv"),index=False)
```

---

Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def deleteSearchTerm(inputFile):
    df = pd.read_csv(inputFile)
    print(df)

#(2) Filter every row where the first letter is 's' from search term
    df = df[~pd.to_numeric(df['ProductOMS'],errors='coerce').isnull()]

    print(df)
    return df.to_csv(inputFile)


inputFile = filePath
inputFile = deleteSearchTerm(inputFile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I tried your code it kept search term though

Comment: Thank you! return to_csv was exactly what I needed! I'll edit your post with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Data from the source csv as shared at the google drive location:

```
'''
productNum,ProductOMS,productPrice,Unnamed: 3
2463448,1002623072,419.95,
2463413,1002622872,289.95,
2463430,1002622974,309.95,
2463419,1002622908,329.95,
2463434,search?searchTerm=2463434,,
2463423,1002622932,469.95,
'''

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Output:

```
   productNum                 ProductOMS  productPrice  Unnamed: 3
0     2463448                 1002623072        419.95         NaN
1     2463413                 1002622872        289.95         NaN
2     2463430                 1002622974        309.95         NaN
3     2463419                 1002622908        329.95         NaN
4     2463434  search?searchTerm=2463434           NaN         NaN
5     2463423                 1002622932        469.95         NaN
```

.

```
df1 = df.loc[df['ProductOMS'].str.isdigit()]

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   productNum  ProductOMS  productPrice  Unnamed: 3
0     2463448  1002623072        419.95         NaN
1     2463413  1002622872        289.95         NaN
2     2463430  1002622974        309.95         NaN
3     2463419  1002622908        329.95         NaN
5     2463423  1002622932        469.95         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I tried it with my dataframe it kept 'searchterm'

Comment: Can you copy and paste the actual contents of the csv file in the question?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the solution is based on the sample data that I created myself based on reading your description from the question. If you can provide with the actual source sample data, that will help.

Comment: Yeah would uploading a copy of it to a google drive help?

Comment: To copy the contents of the csv, I would suggest opening up the csv file in a simple text editor and not in a spreadsheet editor like MS Excel Or Libra

Comment: Ok I added a link to the CSV and I'll try and edit my post to have the dataframe in it

Comment: I fixed the code. It should work now. I have added the correction to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214694/discussion-between-anshul-and-chrishg).

Answer (score 2):

For the most part your function is fine but you seem to have forgotten to **save** the CSV, which is done by `df.to_csv()` method.

Let me rewrite the code for you:

```
import pandas as pd

def processAndSaveCSV(filename):
  # Read the CSV file
  df = pd.read_csv(filename)

  # Retain only the rows with `ProductOMS` being numeric
  df = df[df['ProductOMS'].str.contains('^\d+')]

  # Save CSV File - Rewrites file
  df.to_csv(filename)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm getting the same results of the terminal showing correct output but the excel file is not getting updated from my program

Answer (score 2):

I hope it helps you:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = df[~df['ProductOMS'].str.contains('^[a-z]+')]
df.to_csv(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a scope problem to me.
First we need to return `df`:

```
def deleteSearchTerm(inputFile):
#(1) Open the file

    df = pd.read_csv(inputFile)
    print(df)

#(2) Filter every row where the first letter is 's' from search term
    df = df[~pd.to_numeric(df['ProductOMS'],errors='coerce').isnull()]

    print(df)
    return df
```

Then replace the line

```
DeleteSearchTerm(InputFile)
```

with:

```
InputFile = DeleteSearchTerm(InputFile)
```

Basically your function is not returning anything.
After you fix that you just need to redefine your inputFile variable to the new dataframe your function is returning.

If you already defined df earlier in your code and you're trying to manipulate it, then the function is not actually changing your existing global df variable. Instead it's making a new local variable under the same name.

To fix this we first return the local df and then re-assign the global df to the local one.

You should be able to find more information about variable scope at this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/

It also appears you never actually update your original file.

Try adding this to the end of your code:

```
df.to_csv('CSV file name', index=True)
```

Index just says whether you want to have a line index.

Comment: so i'm facing the same problem where the output on the terminal is fine but my excel file still isn't updating, would you know what could cause that?